# Google Cloud Compute Engine - should I pay for waiting the http request?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want my VM be alive 24/7 but I expect only a few requests each month. Should I pay for waiting the http request?

I read that "All machine types are charged a minimum of 10 minutes. For example, if you run your virtual machine for 2 minutes, you will be billed for 10 minutes of usage."

Should I pay if my VM alive but just only is listening the port (waiting for request)?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) might be more appropriate than running a VM on Google Compute Engine. It's similar to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). If requests will be infrequent then a Cloud Function should be cheaper since you only pay for computation while your code is running. Maintaining it might be easier than maintaining a web server in a VM too.